# LR Test for Exponential Family of Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

LR Test for Exponential Family of Distributions: The exponential family of distributions, both 
discrete and continuous, based on a parameter θ is defined by:

f (x |theta) = c(x)d(theta)exp[a(theta)b(x)]

Show that N(μ,1) is a special case of this family. That is, determine the values for the 
functions a, b, c, and d.

Comment: This is not a question about a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Well the next part of the question is

Suppose that X1,…, Xn are i.i.d. according to a general distribution in the exponential 
family. Consider a hypothesis test of H0: θ = θ0 vs. HA: θ = θ1, where θ0 < θ1. Derive an 
expression for the likelihood ratio test statistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The density of $N(\mu, 1)$ is $$f(x|\mu)
=
\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}}
$$

Just expand the square.

details:
$$f(x|\mu)
=
\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}}
=
\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} e^{-\mu^2/2} e^{x\mu}
$$
so you find (this is not the lonly solution):

$$
c(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}
\\
d(\mu) =  e^{-\mu^2/2}
\\
a(\mu) = \mu
\\
b(x) = x
$$

Comment: I did it out to get f(x|μ)=1/(2π^(1/2))*e^(−(x^2-x*mu+mu^2)/2) I don't understand what the values are for a,b,c, or d from here.

Comment: I made the edit with details.

Comment: Oh I understand now! Thank you so much!